# Requesting less user info with meteor's standard accounts-xxx packages

Tags: meteor, oauth-2.0, meteor-accounts

When using the meteor accounts-google package or accounts-github and others meteor asks for email and other data for example

[image: permissions]

Clicking the info icon highlighted shows

[image: more info]

I don't need any of that info for my app. In fact I don't even need email.

Is it possible to use those account services solely to give the user an account on my service and not request access to any of their info? At most I want their username if they have one they'd prefer but otherwise I don't need email or anything else.

Comment: Have you tried [Meteor.loginwithexternalservice](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice)'s `requestPermissions` option?

Comment: I think I'm confused. I'm using the accounts-ui package to log users in which means I don't manually call Meteor.loginXXX. The accounts-ui package does that for me. I'm currently using `ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert` to set options. It's not clear if I can pass in `requestPermissions` there.

Comment: Use `Accounts.ui.config()` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Services should accept required permissions configuration.

Some services may have required permissions that are added regardless the one specified.

For example, when using Google, the `profile` permission, which is [the basic login scope](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth) and is required in order to get the user id.

## Directly calling the login service package:

The [API](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice) should be:

```
Meteor.loginWith<ExternalService>([options], [callback])
```

For example,

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  requestPermissions: ["email"],
  userEmail: 'foo@bar.me',
  ...
});
```

## Using accounts-ui:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    google: [
      "email", 
      "given_name,
      "family_name"
    ],
    github:[...]
  }
});
```

The available fields are available on the server as `Google.whitelistedFields`.

You can take a look at the [source of the MDG packages](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So AFAICT the answer is no. None of the services have the option of **less** info. Their minimum info seems to be name+email+profile.

Comment: The Google service does not, as it is required in order to get essential data. Other services may be more granular, depending on available API and implementation. If you can get the identification data that is required for the service to work using less info, you can always fork the package locally and change the requested permissions (and preferably open a GitHub issue regarding it).

Comment: It's not an issue of the package. It's the services themselves that are the issue. The service says "this app will get permission to do X" where X currently always includes "know your email address, name, ..." That privacy sensitive people might not want to use my app. I don't need their name, email, or anything. I only need Google/GitHub/Twitter to authenticate them. Unfortunately none of them provide a way to do that without also telling the user they are giving out more info. Sure I can not take the info but the user will still be warned that they're granting permission for me to get it.

Comment: Indeed. This is their decision. Similar issues exist in the "simplified" Android permissions. Other services may provide more granular permission with their API. I share your concerns, but at the moment not much can be done.

Comment: @gman, I modified the Google scopes for one of my projects and was able to avoid using the `profile` scope. I opened an issue on GitHub and will update this answer when I have a bit more definitive information.